# Works up to Android KitKat. I have to run it on Lollipop and up

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Imported from https://github.com/katchsvartanian/voiceRecognition. Whenever I run the project on android version above Kitkat LogCat shows up below error:

```
    JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: illegal class   name 'com.example.jni.FLACStreamEncoder'
    (should be of the form 'package/Class', [Lpackage/Class;' or '[[B')
    in call to FindClass
    from void com.example.jni.FLACStreamEncoder.init(java.lang.String, int, int, int)
```

Shows up error on below line:

```
    init(outfile, sample_rate, channels,  bits_per_sample)
```

in FLACStreamEncoder.java in below function.

```
public FLACStreamEncoder(String outfile, int sample_rate, int channels,int bits_per_sample)
{
    init(outfile, sample_rate, channels, bits_per_sample);
}
```

and in FLACRecorder.java:

```
mEncoder = new FLACStreamEncoder (mPath, sample_rate, mapped_channels,  mapped_format)
```

My FLACStreamEncoder.cpp contains below code and I have changed:

```
    static char const * const FLACStreamEncoder_classname="com.example.jni.FLACStreamEncoder";
```

to

```
    static char const * const FLACStreamEncoder_classname="com/example/jni/FLACStreamEncoder";
```

When I run the code after making the above change and when I move my cursor over the error:

```
    jclass cls = env->FindClass(FLACStreamEncoder_classname);
```

it shows the hint as " jclass and jclass are not compatible ". I am not very good at C++. My FLACStreamEncoder.cpp contains below code.

```
    ...
    static FLACStreamEncoder * get_encoder(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
    {
    assert(sizeof(jlong) >= sizeof(FLACStreamEncoder *));
    // Do the JNI dance for getting the mObject field
    jclass cls = env->FindClass(FLACStreamEncoder_classname);
    jfieldID object_field = env->GetFieldID(cls, FLACStreamEncoder_mObject,"J");
    jlong encoder_value = env->GetLongField(obj, object_field);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);

    return reinterpret_cast<FLACStreamEncoder *>(encoder_value);
    }

    static void set_encoder(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, FLACStreamEncoder *   encoder)
    {
    assert(sizeof(jlong) >= sizeof(FLACStreamEncoder *));

    // Do the JNI dance for setting the mObject field
    jlong encoder_value = reinterpret_cast<jlong>(encoder);
    jclass cls = env->FindClass(FLACStreamEncoder_classname);
    jfieldID object_field = env->GetFieldID(cls, FLACStreamEncoder_mObject,   "J");
    env->SetLongField(obj, object_field, encoder_value);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
    }
    ...
```

I have made the changes following the link [android art runtime check_jni.cc error on package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092044/android-art-runtime-check-jni-cc-error-on-package-name).

What I want to know is even after making the change for the class path why does it show the same error?

```
 'com.example.jni.FLACStreamEncoder' to "com/example/jni/FLACStreamEncoder"
```

it still shows the same error in the LogCat.

Comment: If it still shows `com.example.jni.FLACStreamEncoder` in the error message then perhaps you haven't rebuilt the app properly. The doing a full rebuild.

Comment: I have clean and rebuilt the project but it shows the same error. Infact I commented the below jclass code, still it shows the same error. After commenting it works fine till KItKat :                               
/*  jclass cls = env->FindClass(FLACStreamEncoder_classname);
  jfieldID object_field = env->GetFieldID(cls, FLACStreamEncoder_mObject, "J");
  jlong encoder_value = env->GetLongField(obj, object_field);
  env->DeleteLocalRef(cls); */jlong encoder_value = env->GetLongField(obj, streamer_mObj);
  env->DeleteLocalRef(encoder_value);